# Rails 4 protected attributes in Production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a Rails 4.1 app that was once a 3.2 app. During the course of steadily upgrading the app I originally used the `protected_attributes` gem. I have now removed this gem and specified the proper permit strong params like this:

```
def step_params
  params.require(:step).permit(:display_order, :name, :stepable_id, :stepable_type, :step_type, :image,
                               :image_cache, :image_temp_upload_url, :image_processed,
                               video_attributes: [:description, :video, :video_cache, :video_temp_upload_url],
                               download_attributes: [ :description, :download, :download_cache, :temp_upload_download_url],
                               quiz_attributes: [:description,
                                                 questions_attributes: [:question, :quiz_id,
                                                                        answers_attributes: [:answer, :correct, :question_id]
                                                ]
                                ],
                               reading_attributes: [:reading],
                               slidedeck_attributes: [:description, :slides, :audio, :audio_cache, :audio_temp_upload_url, :audio_duration,
                                                      slides_attributes: [:slide, :slide_cache, :slide_temp_upload_url, :slide_processed, :time]
                                ],
                               voice_over_attributes: [:image, :image_cache, :image_temp_upload_url, :image_processed, :audio, :audio_cache, :audio_temp_upload_url, :audio_duration]
                              )

end
```

This all works perfectly in development. However in production I get this error:

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...=", "step"=>{"name"=>"asdfasdgasfd", "image_temp_upload_url"=>"...", "image_cache"=>"", "stepable_type"=>"Download", "download_attributes"=>{"description"=>"asdasd", "temp_upload_download_url"=>"...", "download_cache"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Save", "subdomain"=>"my", "author_id"=>"61"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Step: name, stepable_type, image_cache, image_temp_upload_url, download_attributes
    app/controllers/my/author/steps_author_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Is there something I've forgotten to remove or??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart the production server?

Comment: Good question. Just checked both the capistrano deploy output and the Unicorn logs and yes, the server does appear to have successfully restarted

Comment: Did you remove the `protected_attributes` gem from your `Gemfile`? Did double check that you removed all `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` calls from your application?

Comment: actually @RSB was right after all. I rebooted the EC2 instance and then restarted the app again and it all magically worked. Now I need to go work out why my deploy scripts aren't restarting everything properly :(